# Android: TextView Causing App to Crash

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to get a TextView to display a string depending on a condition. However, when I tried to implement it, it causes the app to stop working. Here is the relevant code/xml:

```
// class declaration, etc.
TextView textString;

// other code

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);
    ...
    textString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textId);
    ...

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_id:
        ...

            if(getNum(0) == 10) {
                textString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textId);
                textString.setText("String 1");
            }
            if(getNum(1) == 10) {
                textString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textId);
                textString.setText("String 2");
            }
            // etc.
```

getNum(int index) is a method I wrote that returns an integer from an array given an index.

XML Code for TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/other_id"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />
```

Why is it crashing?

Edit* Here is the the LogCat:

[image]

I am not sure how much of it you need.

Comment: May we have a LogCat output? You also don't need to do `textString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textId);` every time if textString is already global.

Comment: Why you initializing textString again in onClick?

Comment: I am trying to get the LogCat data. Give me a minute.

Comment: Where are you casting into a Button? That's interesting. I think you probably are using the wrong id at that line, *wherever* it is.

Comment: This TextView is not your problem, you have a ClassCastException. Highlight the errors in your LogCat the use cut & paste it here, along with more of your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: I am not. It is a TextView. It is not in a Button tag either in the xml.

Comment: IF your code is good and consistent, button = button and textview = textview, clean your project.  I've seen issues like this resolved by using the clean function in eclipse.

Comment: @Sam How much more do you need? The program was working properly until I added the TextView statements. There is nothing else in the onCreate() except for a couple of other TextViews and Buttons.

Comment: @lord_sneed Your full logcat as text and full code would be appreciated. Thing is, A classcastexception is very specific, something probably tiny has changed.

Comment: @logray Cleaning the project actually made it work. If you want to put that as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @logray Or do you want me to answer my own question with that and accept?

Comment: When eclipse messes up I die a bit inside.

Comment: @A--C indeed, sneed, it is now an answer, thx.  glad it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF your code is good and consistent, button = button and textview = textview, clean your project. I've seen issues like this resolved by using the clean function in eclipse.

Comment: This fixed the problem. I will clean the code on a regular basis now.